# Unable to open R Studio on Mac

Tags: r, rstudio

Termination Reason:    DYLD, [0x1] Library missing

Application Specific Information:
dyld: launch, loading dependent libraries

Dyld Error Message:
Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libssl.1.1.dylib
Referenced from: /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/MacOS/RStudio
Reason: no suitable image found.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Hey! Thank you. The issue is resolved now.